# Disable pull down to exit full screen mode on safari ios

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, fullscreen

My team is developing a web application which has a full screen option in some sections. On Chrome, FireFox and Edge, the full screen option works fine. However, on safari ios, when entering full screen mode, if users touch and pull down the screen, it will exit full screen mode. Is there anyway to disable this action?

Comment: No there is not. If you want to consider making this a Web App, then you can have users add this to their home screen and you won't have this problem.

Comment: @quicVO I just saw this after posting. Correct, this is a platform design thing.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I know to solve this is to have your users add the site to the home screen.

I think you can also detect if it's been opened via the home screen.

Comment: Yea, I figured that might be it. It messes up a scrollable full-screen mode in our application, and I was hoping someone had a fancy (read: hacky) workaround.

Comment: Another glaring example of Apple's hostility towards open web platform. Gotta get that App Store money...